# How am I supposed to pass class data to my Views using Codeigniter?

Tags: model-view-controller, oop, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter to build a web app, and I'm trying to follow proper OOP, MVC and Codeigniter convention.  A few things are definitely escaping me.  Below is a simplified explanation of what's confusing me.

I have a 'companies' table and a Companies_model.  This model has private variables like id, name, and url.  This model has a method named load_data( $id ), that uses an id to load all the data about a company into the class variables.  This $id is coming from the URL.  Finally, this model has public getters that return the values.

I have a profile page on my website for every company in my system.  In my Companies controller, I load this company's data in the following way.

```
$this->load->model( 'Companies_model', 'Companies_profile' );
$this->Companies_profile->load_data( $this->uri_company_id );
```

When my other logic is complete in the controller, I have the following code to render the view:

```
$this->data['Companies_profile'] = $this->Companies_profile;
$this->load->view( 'profiles/companies_profile_view', $this->data );
```

In my view, I render data like this:

```
<p>This company's name is <?php echo $Company_profile->get_name(); ?>.</p>
```

All of this seems redundant.  Why am I passing data to the view when it's already available in a specific instantiation of the Companies_method?  I feel confused and that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what that is.  Perhaps I'm not doing anything wrong, but haven't encountered the reason for some of this structure yet.  Overall, my app is fairly simple.  Can someone shed light on how to properly organize and pass data to views?  Why pass the data, and not just make it all available in CI's base class, $this?

NOTE: I have multiple instantiations of the Companies_model on every page I render because I have a list of related companies on each profile page.

Answer (score 2):

That is MVC, at least the way it's done in CodeIgniter. Separation of displaying values from retrieving them from the database. In such simple cases, the advantages are not really visible.

Imagine you later decide to change the database structure. You would only need to rewrite the model to return the same classes and leave front-end code intact. You can also give the view to some web designer to design, without telling him anything about database structure, etc, etc.

One of the main advantages of MVC shows up when you work in teams. Instead of coming up with your own conventions, everyone can do the stuff uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a class object to he view breaks the idea behind MVC.  MVC is designed to break up the parts of programming into 3 aspects.  The Model, View and Controller.  What you pass to the view are only things that the view needs.  The view probably doesn't need the entire object.  It probably only needs certain bits of information from the object.  It allows you to keep the business logic away from the visual design.  It allows a web designer who knows HTML and a little PHP to go in and make changes without having to know how your objects work.  he sees.

```
<?php echo $company_name ?>
```

which is a lot easier for a non technical person to interpret than

```
<?php echo $company->getName(); ?>
```